# Replacing pendant but there are extra live wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I was going to replace a pendant light. But during removal of the old one I've come across this wiring which don't really understand.

The thick brown one on the left is the live wire which is connected to the switch. Along with the blue neutral this is where the light was connected.

The three thin brown wires in the middle are live (regardless of the switch).
What are these for and what should I do with them when I connect my new pendant fixture which doesn't have connectors for these.

[image: wiring]

Comment: Where in the world are you? That will help identify wiring standards.

Comment: @Matthew Im in UK

Comment: Why are you messing with it? That's a standard, common UK terminal block, really nifty setup.  It's wired fine the way it is, attach your lamp's hot and neutral to the outermost 2 lugs and Bob's your uncle.  The terminal block that comes with the lamp is only a courtesy in case you need one, you don't *have* to change it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I would love to not mess with it of course. Sorry it's first time I'm trying to change it myself and didn't realise that there is a common UK terminal block. The new one I got from Amazon. I guess it's not a UK standard as the cover of the terminal block is not screwable, but has to be secured using to bolts
[here is the picture](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Z5xumyMvL._AC_SL1500_.jpg)

Comment: There's your trouble. Thanks to "Amazon Marketplace" (which basically turned Amazon into eBay)... it is awash in cheap Chinese crud that doesn't follow anybody's safety standards or form-factors. They're just like "lotsa luck", they are betting you won't ask for your money back.

Comment: If your new lamp did not come with instructions on how to install it on a ceiling rose, or with a new bracket that REPLACES the ceiling rose (and instructions for that), or with any other instructions on how it can be mounted in the UK .... I would return it.  It looks like they took a USA design and half-adapted it to the UK but left the US canopy.

Comment: Yes, exactly... the lamp's cross bracket is *precisely* for a US "octagon box", which is a ~85mm circular box inset into the ceiling, which provides room for all wire splices.  It looks to me like they did nothing at all to adapt it to the UK market.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your pendant to the leftmost and rightmost terminal in this picture.  Your pendant should have brown and blue wires that correspond.   If it has a yellow, green, or bare wire connect that to the corresponding large terminal at the top of the picture.

One brown/blue pair in the center set of terminals is power coming in, and another brown/blue pair is power going to the next pendant.  The third brown wire in the middle triplet goes off to the light switch, and the leftmost one is switched power coming back for the pendant.

Comment: Re 1st paragraph, I understand how to connect the pendant, My problem is that the new one comes with a cover that cannot be mounted to this terminal. See my comment https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/221375/replacing-pendant-but-there-are-extra-live-wires?noredirect=1#comment415560_221375

Regarding 2nd paragraph, thanks for explaining the wiring. But in that room I only have one pendant. Can it be that it is going to the adjacent room?

Comment: Ok your question was about the wiring, and now I see the issue is that the new pendant is not designed for a ceiling rose like this.  There is a different mounting bracket you need.  If the new canopy fits easily over the ceiling rose (without screwing on) you may be able to install the new bracket behind the ceiling rose so you don't need new electrical connectors.  Did the new lamp not come with a bracket?  A flat piece of metal with the two ends bent at 90 degrees.

Comment: Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfxaVRM4W3c and watch other similar videos on "replace ceiling rose with modern light fitting".

Answer (score 0):

The three browns need to stay connected together to provide power to the switch for this and to other installed lamps.

You could use a 3-way Wago block or other approved connector.
you'll need the same for the blues unless your new lamp provides a connector for them too.

Answer (score 0):

### That "eBay special" is not made for the UK market.

Amazon has a program called "Amazon Marketplace" where anybody can sell anything on the Amazon platform, and the listings lurk among real Amazon listings.  This means Amazon is full of eBay-tier junk, and it is flooded with cheap Chinese merchandise which ignores every safety regulation, and obviously doen't care about fitment either.

They were *aiming* for the North American market and others where you have a junction box inset into the ceiling, like this.  (the surface of the box is flush with the ceiling).

[image]

Needless to say, it's the wrong form-factor for a UK home, and it was negligent to even sell it into your market.   They don't care; "nobody" demands refunds on faulty goods in this day and age.  I would do exactly that.   If the Amazon return window has expired, phone up Amazon and raise a ruckus. They'll credit you, and even pay for the return shipping (if they even want it back, not likely).

How is it *supposed* to work? Easy. Here's your pic, marked up.  The pipe with the cable going through it (green) is threaded on the outside. The cross-bar is just there for shipping (and it's upside-down lol).  You're meant to 1) remove it, and 2) run the screws (red, orange) into the ears on the junction box (which are flush with the ceiling). Then 3) thread the lamp's cable through the center hole (green) and 4) do the electrical connections (hence, not attaching the live+neutral to the junction block - can't til now). Finally 5) the entire fixture is screwed into the center hole (green).   This is a bog-standard way in North America, but it obviously doesn't work without a recessed junction box!

[image]